# Simple C# API Get Request with Auth credentials?

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, api, request

I am a beginner with C# programming. I have experience with Python, and this is essentially what I am trying to replicate with C#.

```py
import requests, json

api_user = "userexample@example.com"
api_key = "keyexample"
url = "https://api.example.com/"

response = requests.get(url, auth=(api_user, api_key))
json_response = response.json()

print(json_response)
```

What would that code look like? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please detail what you have already tried in C# and why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` library to connect with your api server.
Here is the sample code with api basic authentication.
Make sure to call `Dispose()` in the end, or you may get some GC issues.

```
public static class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var apiUser = "userexample@example.com";
            var apiKey = "keyexample";
            var url = "https://api.example.com/";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.example.com/");

            var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{apiUser}:{apiKey}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var content = response.Content;
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```